# javascript Welcome modal only disappears partially

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal window opening when the page loads.

It opens well, however, when I close it, it does not disappear completely, as the grey body-background stays, plus the link in the back become disabled.

I must have got something wrong in the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass('four');
  $('body').addClass('modal-active');
})

$('#modal-container').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('out');
});
```

```css
html.modal-active, body.modal-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  z-index: 5;
}

#modal-container.four {
  z-index: 4;
  transform: scale(1);
}
#modal-container.four .modal-background {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);;
}
#modal-container.four .modal-background .modal {
  animation: blowUpModal 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four + .content-formodal {
  z-index: 5;
  animation: blowUpContent 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four.out .modal-background .modal {
  animation: blowUpModalTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four.out + .content-formodal {
  animation: blowUpContentTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}

#modal-container .modal-background {
  display: table-cell;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal {
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal .modal-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal .modal-svg rect {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 778;
  stroke-dashoffset: 778;
}


@keyframes blowUpContent {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@keyframes blowUpContentTwo {
  0% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes blowUpModal {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes blowUpModalTwo {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }

.linkclass {

  color: #283446;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'geomanistregular';
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color: white">

<div id="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="modal">
      <h2>I'm a Modal</h2>
      <p>Hear me roar.</p>
      <svg class="modal-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="226" height="162" rx="3" ry="3"></rect>
              </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content-formodal">

 <a href="#"><p class="linkclass">LINK</p></a>   

</div> <!-- content-formodal -->

</body>
```

Basically, when I click anywhere, I would like the modal to disappear completely and leave room to everything else behind it. Right now, it is not the case.

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the grey body-background disappear too.

According to your current code, there is one solution using purely CSS.

Because you an animation, `display: none` will not satisfy your need. Therefore, setting `z-index` to `-1` to `#modal-container.four` can solve your problem.

```
#modal-container.out .modal-background {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
#modal-container.four {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

You can twist it around yourself to suit your implementation.

Working code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass('four');
  $('body').addClass('modal-active');
})

$('#modal-container').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('out');
});

$('a').click(function(){
    alert('link is clicked');
});
```

```css
html.modal-active, body.modal-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  z-index: 5;
}

/* ADDED THIS BLOCK */
#modal-container.out .modal-background {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.7s;
}

#modal-container.four {
  z-index: -1; /* CHANGED THIS FROM 4 TO -1 */
  transform: scale(1);
}
#modal-container.four .modal-background {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);;
}
#modal-container.four .modal-background .modal {
  animation: blowUpModal 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four + .content-formodal {
  z-index: 5;
  animation: blowUpContent 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four.out .modal-background .modal {
  animation: blowUpModalTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}
#modal-container.four.out + .content-formodal {
  animation: blowUpContentTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}

#modal-container .modal-background {
  display: table-cell;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal {
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal .modal-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#modal-container .modal-background .modal .modal-svg rect {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 778;
  stroke-dashoffset: 778;
}


@keyframes blowUpContent {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
@keyframes blowUpContentTwo {
  0% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes blowUpModal {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes blowUpModalTwo {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }

.linkclass {

  color: #283446;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'geomanistregular';
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color: white">

<div id="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-background">
    <div class="modal">
      <h2>I'm a Modal</h2>
      <p>Hear me roar.</p>
      <svg class="modal-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="226" height="162" rx="3" ry="3"></rect>
              </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content-formodal">

 <a href="#"><p class="linkclass">LINK</p></a>   

</div> <!-- content-formodal -->

</body>
```

Comment: That link still not clickable, check

Comment: @YongQuan , can you please check your code because I cannot click the link behind, still. – mattvent 11 mins ago

Comment: @mattvent I checked and I confirmed that that link is clickable. If you mean after clicking there's no respond, that's the correct respond because no link is included in the `<a>` tag. I've added an alert trigger upon clicking to make it obvious. You may try again.

Comment: It works, thanks. I had  "html {height: 100%;}" in my code and it messed up the whole thing. Do you have an idea of why ?

Comment: how did it messed up? Have you tried using `html, body {height: 100%}`?  I suggest you to post another question for it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:none` to `.out` will solve the issue, as you are playing with `opacity` which will hide but the display area still occupied! Check below snippet for reference.

**Updated:**

```
 #modal-container.out{
   display: none;
 }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#modal-container').removeAttr('class').addClass('four');
  $('body').addClass('modal-active');
})

$('#modal-container').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('out');
});
```

```css
  html.modal-active,
body.modal-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
  z-index: 5;
}

#modal-container.out{
  display: none;
}

#modal-container.four {
  z-index: 4;
  transform: scale(1);
}

#modal-container.four .modal-background {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  ;
}

#modal-container.four .modal-background .modal {
  animation: blowUpModal 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}

#modal-container.four+.content-formodal {
  z-index: 5;
  animation: blowUpContent 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}

#modal-container.four.out .modal-background .modal {
  animation: blowUpModalTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}

#modal-container.four.out+.content-formodal {
  animation: blowUpContentTwo 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) forwards;
}

#modal-container .modal-background {
  display: table-cell;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#modal-container .modal-background .modal {
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
}

#modal-container .modal-background .modal h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#modal-container .modal-background .modal p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

#modal-container .modal-background .modal .modal-svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#modal-container .modal-background .modal .modal-svg rect {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 778;
  stroke-dashoffset: 778;
}

@keyframes blowUpContent {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99.9% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}

@keyframes blowUpContentTwo {
  0% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blowUpModal {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes blowUpModalTwo {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .linkclass {
    color: #283446;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'geomanistregular';
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="background-color: white">

  <div id="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-background">
      <div class="modal">
        <h2>I'm a Modal</h2>
        <p>Hear me roar.</p>
        <svg class="modal-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <rect x="0" y="0" fill="none" width="226" height="162" rx="3" ry="3"></rect>
              </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-formodal">

    <a href="#">
      <p class="linkclass">LINK</p>
    </a>

  </div>
  <!-- content-formodal -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following CSS to hide the modal container entirly:

```
#modal-container.out {
    display: none;
}
```